Bitbucket Pipelines: Unable to Execute Multiple Reusable Steps in a Custom Pipeline
I'm encountering an issue where I cannot get multiple reusable steps to execute sequentially in a custom pipeline in Bitbucket. My goal is to set up AWS credentials and then deploy a Go application, but the pipeline stops after executing only the first step.
Here's a simplified version of my pipeline configuration and the different approaches I've tried:
Pipeline Configuration:
image: golang:1.22

definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &setup-aws-credentials
        name: Setup AWS Credentials
        oidc: true
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl unzip
          - curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
          - unzip awscliv2.zip
          - ./aws/install
          - aws --version
          # Additional commands for AWS CLI setup...

    - step: &manual-deploy-script
        name: Manual Deploy to Dev
        script:
          - # Script for deployment...

pipelines:
  custom:
    Deploy:
      - step:
          <<: *setup-aws-credentials
          <<: *manual-deploy-script

Attempt 1: Using YAML merge <<: to include both steps under a single - step.
This approach only runs the setup-aws-credentials step, and the manual-deploy-script does not execute. There are no specific error messages; the pipeline simply does not proceed past the first script.
Attempt 2: Combining scripts in a single step sequence.
pipelines:
  custom:
    Deploy:
      - step:
          name: Deploy to Development
          script:
            - *setup-aws-credentials
            - *manual-deploy-script

This modification results in a YAML parsing error, as the syntax does not support direct inclusion of anchors in the script array.

There is an error in your bitbucket-pipelines.yml at [pipelines >
custom > Deploy > 0 > step > script > 0]. Missing or empty command
string. Each item in this list should either be a single command
string or a map defining a pipe invocation.

Question:
How can I correctly structure my Bitbucket pipeline to execute both the AWS credential setup and the application deployment scripts sequentially when triggered? I'm looking for a way to reuse these steps without having to duplicate the script contents.
I'd appreciate any insights or examples of how to properly configure multiple reusable steps in Bitbucket Pipelines.

I assume you want to just share the scripts while keeping the full step definition? This is how I have set things up in my pipeline to, which makes the script steps be ran in a single block. This doesnt leave the nicest looking runs but as it has worked for me so far, and nearly never fails, it is acceptable.
Basically just define the script blocks separately and then place them in your defined steps. You can then reuse and combine the script definitions in your custom combo.
image: golang:1.22

definitions:
  scripts:
    - script: &aws-setup-scripts |-
          apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl unzip
          curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
          unzip awscliv2.zip
          ./aws/install
          aws --version
          # Additional commands for AWS CLI setup...
   - script: &same-for-these |-
          # Script for deployment...
  steps:
    - step: &setup-aws-credentials
        name: Setup AWS Credentials
        oidc: true
        script:
          - *aws-setup-script

    - step: &manual-deploy-script
        name: Manual Deploy to Dev
        script:
          - *same-for-these

pipelines:
  custom:
    Deploy:
      - step:
          - *aws-setup-scripts
          - *same-for-these

